# How to replace a specific li content with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="widget_ex_attachments">
    <ul>
            <li>
            <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
            <a href="uploads/2014/09/Parellel-universe.docx">Parellel universe</a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
            <a href="uploads/2014/09/The-List-v5.6.xls">The List v5.6</a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
            <a href="uploads/2014/09/cv.pdf">cv</a>
            </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to target only `<i>` tags that are inside an `<li>` tag that has `<a>` whose "href" contains string ".doc".

To make more sense, this is what I did:

```
$( '.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]' ).parent('li').replaceWith( '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>' );
```

-the problem, of course, is that whole `<li>` content was replaced with new `<i>` tag.
I have tried:

```
$( '.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]' ).parent('li:first').replaceWith( '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>' );
$( '.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]' ).parent('li:first-child').replaceWith( '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>' );
$( '.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]' ).parent('li i').replaceWith( '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>' );
```

-none of it works...

Can someone, please, tell me how do I target this tag element. Thank you.

Comment: so replace it with the whole code including <li> tag

Comment: So you're basically changing the class of the preceding `<i>` from `fa-file-word-o` to `fa-file-pdf-o`? Why not just do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try find :

```
$('.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]' ).parent('li').find('i').replaceWith( '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>' );
```

See it in action :

http://jsfiddle.net/58ardu6h/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( '.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]' ).prev('i').replaceWith( '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`find` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `i` element inside the `li`:

```
$('.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]').parent('li').find('i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>');
```

You can also move from the link to the previous element using the [`prev` method](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) (assuming of course that it always is right there):

```
$('.widget_ex_attachments a[href*=".doc"]').prev().replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>');
```

Another approach is to use the [`has` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to find the `li` elements that have that link in them:

```
$('.widget_ex_attachments li').has('a[href*=".doc"]').find('i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>');
```